# Unable to change Spring security access denied standard response

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I have a Spring Boot application in which I used OAuth with Spring Security. When I requests an authorization token to Spring Security it returns the following response:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}
```

I need to change that response to a custom json, but none of the approaches I have tried works.

I have tried to use a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` like the following:

```
public class CustomOAuth2AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler{

    public CustomOAuth2AccessDeniedHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getOutputStream().println("Exception with message : " + authException.getMessage());
        //doHandle(request, response, authException);

    }
```

but it does not get called. Using `web.xml` to redirect response is not an option for me since I am using Spring Boot, and I do not want to change the format of the response globally.

My `spring-security.xml` is configured like this:

```
<!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest"/>
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client"/>
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" -->
<!--       class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/> -->
<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="in.robotrack.brad.config.CustomOAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>


<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token Store  -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    <!-- VIV -->
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

try bellow:

```
HttpSecurity http = ...
http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(myAccessDeniedHandler);
```

if you don't want to define your custom AccessdeniedHandler then even you can try this

```
HttpSecurity http = ...
http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

And then in your controller just define one method that can handle /403 request mapping and there you just return your 403 error page, as you do in normal methods inside any controller class.

Comment: The AccessDeniedHandler only applies to authenticated users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057592/spring-boot-accessdeniedhandler-does-not-work