# Spring Boot + REST + Spring Security: how to generate a custom JSON response for HTTP 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring-Boot REST controller, protected by Spring-Security. It works fine. If the client sends an HTTP request without having the proper access token on the HTTP header then he gets back an HTTP 403 response, as I expect.

**curl -i localhost:8301/user/11:**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 16:25:45 GMT

{
  "timestamp" : 1573143945072,
  "status" : 403,
  "error" : "Forbidden",
  "message" : "Access Denied",
  "path" : "/user/11"
}
```

I also have a custom error handler, it handles all the errors appear in the REST methods:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(json, httpStatus);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(json, httpStatus);
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to customize the error response in case of HTTP 403 and I want to send back a custom JSON response to the client (same JSON what I send back in the `ControllerExceptionHandler`).

Unfortunately, the error handler above does not handle the HTTP 403 because the request is blocked by Spring-Security somewhere before it reaches my REST method.

It seems that I need to add some extra code to Spring Security but I am not sure.

Could you please put me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057592/spring-boot-accessdeniedhandler-does-not-work  ... you should override this `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(...)` ... i test it, it works

Comment: I am still confused about how Spring Security manages/distinguishes HTTP 401 and HTTP 403. As I can see httpSecurity.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint() handles HTTP401 because this class is activated if there is no auth token on the HTTP header. How to catch the lack of permission issues (HTTP 403)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot uses **BasicErrorController** as a global error handler. i.e. Exceptions that are not handled by **@ExceptionHander** methods. To override this default behavior, you need to implement **ErrorController** interface as shown below.

**CustomErrorController.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/error", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/errror";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
        if (status == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(status);
        }
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("status", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        body.put("error", "Forbidden");
        body.put("message", "My Custom Error Message");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, status);
    }

    protected HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if (statusCode == null) {
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
        try {
            return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
    }

}
```

**Please note** that, with this approach, you are overriding the response for all exceptions (not just AccessDeniedException) which are not handled by other **@ExceptionHandler** methods.

If you don't want that and you want to override the response only for **AccessDeniedException** then you need to implement **AccessDeniedHandler** interface as shown below and add it to your spring security's http configuration.

**CustomAccessDeniedHandler.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        body.put("timestamp", new Date());
        body.put("status", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        body.put("error", "Forbidden");
        body.put("message", "Custom Error Message from CustomAccessDeniedHandler");
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        new Gson().toJson(body, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType(), response.getWriter());

    }

}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler()).and().httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().disable();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Message> handleException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Throwable ex) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by overwriting your http.execptionalHandling().authenticationEntryPoint() in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a custom authentication entry point class like this.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.error("Responding for UnAuthorized request{} ", authException.getMessage());
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
}
```

}