# Spring security throw unauthorized instead of redirecting to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I wish that my spring web application would simply return status code `403 UNAUTHORIZED` instead of redirecting to `/login` when user is trying to access resource without being logged in or having the correct authorities.

I currently have my spring security set up with `oauth2` client login, but I believe it has the same behavior with basic login as well.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/allowed").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login(this::configureOauthLogin) // sets up custom user services
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            });
}
```

I've tried dealing with it with providing `accessDeniedHandler` but I don't see that it changes anything as this handler is never actually triggered.

**TLDR**

Make spring throw `403` instead of `302` on unauthorized requests.

**EDIT**

Here's a dump of my filter chain

```
filters = {ArrayList@6668}  size = 14
 0 = {WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6635} 
 1 = {SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6634} 
 2 = {HeaderWriterFilter@6633} 
 3 = {LogoutFilter@6632} 
 4 = {OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@6631} 
 5 = {OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@6630} 
 6 = {DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@6629} 
 7 = {DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6628} 
 8 = {RequestCacheAwareFilter@6627} 
 9 = {SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6626} 
 10 = {AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6625} 
 11 = {SessionManagementFilter@6624} 
 12 = {ExceptionTranslationFilter@6623} 
 13 = {FilterSecurityInterceptor@6622}
```

Comment: But if it redirect to login the the login failed so it's a 401. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057592/spring-boot-accessdeniedhandler-does-not-work

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I don't see how this statement is true. Redirect's can only happen on 3xx response codes, I would be perfectly content if it would return 401 or 403. 

Also `curl -v localhost:8080/denied` -> `HTTP/1.1 302`

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Ah, I see, the OP in your posted question wants to redirect the user to a page that's literally just called `403`, thus your confusion. Alas that's not what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out this flow of controll is handled by `authenticationEntryPoint` in the security config. The following code provides the desired behavior:

```
         http   
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
```